# Syncing options for iPhone/iPod Touch besides Google and Outlook

Tags: iphone, sync, ipod-touch, software-rec, address-book

I want to sync my **iPod Touch address book** to something other than **MS Outlook** (don't want to pay for it) and **Google** (don't trust them to protect my personal data) on a Windows machine. **Do I have any other options?**

Thunderbird, ACT!, etc. any other option I would be interested in looking into beside buying a Mac.  I haven't been able to find any after searching the internet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did some searching and I have found. Companionlink as a possible option between programs, albeit a little costly, but cheaper than $99 for MoblieMe.  http://www.companionlink.com/products/companionlink.html

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you don't want to have to pay but the only other option I can think of is [MobileMe](http://me.com) which costs $99/year.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have any other options?

None.

---

Mr. Man mentions [MobileMe](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/), which totally slipped my mind. Costs $99 a year.

Comment: The only other one I can think of is MobileMe but that costs $99/year.

Comment: True., might want to post it as a separate answer @Mr. Man

Comment: Alright. Done ^_^